# What is the derivative of $\frac{\partial (1/y)}{\partial (w/y)}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $\frac{\partial (1/y)}{\partial (w/y)}$ if
$Z = \alpha w+(1-\alpha)y$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)?$ Clearly, $\frac{\partial (Z/y)}{\partial (w/y)}=\alpha.$ Does that mean $\frac{\partial (1/y)}{\partial (w/y)}=\frac{\alpha}{Z}?$ If so, what are the steps to get there?

Comment: You're looking for the first derivative or the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put
$$
x = w/y \Rightarrow x/w = 1/y,
$$

so we get
$$
\frac{\partial (x/w)}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{w}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to evaluate $\frac{\partial (1/y)}{\partial (w/y)}$ is to observe that from $Z = \alpha w+(1-\alpha)y$, we have $$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{\alpha \left ( \frac{w}{y} +(1-\alpha)\right )}{Z}$$ and now is is clear that $$\frac{\partial (1/y)}{\partial (w/y)} =\frac{\alpha }{Z}$$